# Extract info from file

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing

Is there an efficient way to parse a file like:

```
2       41620   .       T       G       100     PASS    AC=3;AF=0.000599042;AN=5008;NS=2504;DP=18872;EAS_AF=0;AMR_AF=0;AFR_AF=0;EUR_AF=0;SAS_AF=0.0031;AA=.|||;CSQ=G|ENSG00000184731|ENST00000327669|Transcript|missense_variant|954|954|318|K/N|aaA/aaC|||-1|tolerated(0.47)|benign(0)||||;GENCODE=ENST00000327669
```

to:

```
CSQ=G      ENSG00000184731         ENST00000327669    Transcript  missense_variant
```

The patten is always `|||`; - then it starts with `CSQ` and it ends with the fifth field - however that field is not always `missense variant` but can also be something different like `kdjdud`.

There are many (over 60k) lines in the file and I would need to extract this tab deli table as shown above - is there a Python , Perl or AWK (or something else) solution for that?

Answer (score 3):

Let's use `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/.*\|\|\|;(CSQ[^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|.*/\1\t\2\t\3\t\4\t\5/' file.txt
```

`python` is not fast at manipulating very large file, this would be much faster than `python`.

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt 
2       41620   .       T       G       100     PASS    AC=3;AF=0.000599042;AN=5008;NS=2504;DP=18872;EAS_AF=0;AMR_AF=0;AFR_AF=0;EUR_AF=0;SAS_AF=0.0031;AA=.|||;CSQ=G|ENSG00000184731|ENST00000327669|Transcript|missense_variant|954|954|318|K/N|aaA/aaC|||-1|tolerated(0.47)|benign(0)||||;GENCODE=ENST00000327669
2       41620   .       T       G       100     PASS    AC=3;AF=0.000599042;AN=5008;NS=2504;DP=18872;EAS_AF=0;AMR_AF=0;AFR_AF=0;EUR_AF=0;SAS_AF=0.0031;AA=.|||;CSQ=G|ENSG00000184731|ENST00000327669|Transcript|missense_variant|954|954|318|K/N|aaA/aaC|||-1|tolerated(0.47)|benign(0)||||;GENCODE=ENST00000327669
2       41620   .       T       G       100     PASS    AC=3;AF=0.000599042;AN=5008;NS=2504;DP=18872;EAS_AF=0;AMR_AF=0;AFR_AF=0;EUR_AF=0;SAS_AF=0.0031;AA=.|||;CSQ=G|ENSG00000184731|ENST00000327669|Transcript|missense_variant|954|954|318|K/N|aaA/aaC|||-1|tolerated(0.47)|benign(0)||||;GENCODE=ENST00000327669
2       41620   .       T       G       100     PASS    AC=3;AF=0.000599042;AN=5008;NS=2504;DP=18872;EAS_AF=0;AMR_AF=0;AFR_AF=0;EUR_AF=0;SAS_AF=0.0031;AA=.|||;CSQ=G|ENSG00000184731|ENST00000327669|Transcript|missense_variant|954|954|318|K/N|aaA/aaC|||-1|tolerated(0.47)|benign(0)||||;GENCODE=ENST00000327669

% sed -r 's/.*\|\|\|;(CSQ[^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|.*/\1\t\2\t\3\t\4\t\5/' file.txt
CSQ=G   ENSG00000184731 ENST00000327669 Transcript  missense_variant
CSQ=G   ENSG00000184731 ENST00000327669 Transcript  missense_variant
CSQ=G   ENSG00000184731 ENST00000327669 Transcript  missense_variant
CSQ=G   ENSG00000184731 ENST00000327669 Transcript  missense_variant
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Perl:

```bsh
perl -F'\|\|\|' -lane '$, = "\t"; @f = split(/;|\|/, $F[1]); shift(@f); splice(@f, 5); print(@f)' file
```

- `-F'\|\|\|'`: sets the input field separator to `|||`;
- `-l`: enables automatic line-ending processing. It has two separate effects. First, it automatically chomps $/ (the input record separator) when used with -n or -p. Second, it assigns $\ (the output record separator) to have the value of octnum so that any print statements will have that separator added back on. If octnum is omitted, sets $\ to the current value of $/.
- `-a`: turns on autosplit mode when used with a -n or -p. An implicit split command to the @F array is done as the first thing inside the implicit while loop produced by the -n or -p.
- `n`: causes Perl to assume the following loop around your program, which makes it iterate over filename arguments somewhat like sed -n or awk:

  ```perl
  LINE:
    while (<>) {
        ...             # your program goes here
    }
  ```
- `-e`: may be used to enter one line of program.
- `$, = "\t"; @f = split(/;|\|/, $F[1]); shift(@f); splice(@f, 5); print(@f)`: sets the output field separator to `\t`, splits the second field of the current line on `;` or `|`, removes the first empty field and prints the remaining fields.

```bsh
% cat file
2       41620   .       T       G       100     PASS    AC=3;AF=0.000599042;AN=5008;NS=2504;DP=18872;EAS_AF=0;AMR_AF=0;AFR_AF=0;EUR_AF=0;SAS_AF=0.0031;AA=.|||;CSQ=G|ENSG00000184731|ENST00000327669|Transcript|missense_variant|954|954|318|K/N|aaA/aaC|||-1|tolerated(0.47)|benign(0)||||;GENCODE=ENST00000327669
% perl -F'\|\|\|' -lane '$, = "\t"; @f = split(/;|\|/, $F[1]); shift(@f); splice(@f, 5); print(@f)' file
CSQ=G   ENSG00000184731 ENST00000327669 Transcript  missense_variant
%
```

Comment: How do I make a Flat Earth? *Perl!*  **;-)**

Comment: @dn-ʞɔɐqɹW And what do you grow on it? Onions!

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
cut -d"|" -f4,5,6,7,8 filename.txt | sed 's/;//g' | sed 's/|/\t/g'
```

Example:

```
$ echo "2       41620   .       T       G       100     PASS    AC=3;AF=0.000599042;AN=5008;NS=2504;DP=18872;EAS_AF=0;AMR_AF=0;AFR_AF=0;EUR_AF=0;SAS_AF=0.0031;AA=.|||;CSQ=G|ENSG00000184731|ENST00000327669|Transcript|missense_variant|954|954|318|K/N|aaA/aaC|||-1|tolerated(0.47)|benign(0)||||;GENCODE=ENST00000327669
" | cut -d"|" -f4,5,6,7,8 | sed 's/;//g' | sed 's/|/\t/g'

CSQ=G   ENSG00000184731 ENST00000327669 Transcript  missense_variant
```

Explanation

```
cut -d"|" -f4,5,6,7,8 filename.txt   #-> split the line at | and return fields 4 to 8
| sed 's/;//g'                       #-> remove the ;
| sed 's/|/\t/g'                     #-> replace | with tab
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Python solution

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re,sys
with open(sys.argv[1]) as fd:
    for line in fd:
        pattern=[ x for x in re.split('\|\|\||;',line)
                    if 'CSQ' in x]
        if pattern:
            print(" ".join(pattern[0].split("|")[0:5]))
```

#### TEST

With OP's original line repasted 3 times and slightly edited into `input.txt`

```
$ ./extract_pattern.py input.txt                                                                      
CSQ=G ENSG00000184731 ENST00000327669 Transcript missense_variant
CSQ=G ENSG00000184731 ENST00000327669 Transcript random_variant
CSQ=G ENSG00000184731 ENST00000327669 Transcript other_variant
```

#### Explanation

The script opens file given on command-line as argument (`sys.argv[1]`) and reads the file line by line. We first use `re.split()` function to break down each line on multiple delimiters - 3 vertical bars or `;` , which allows the relevant data to be contained within one string. We then find that one string ( which contains `CSQ` ). If we find it, the string is split into list of strings again , now only using `.split()` function using vertical bar as delimiter. The resulting list is sliced to take first 5 elements (the `[0:5]` part) and rejoined into a new string using space as delimiter.